# Could not load source: SourceRequest not supported

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bazel

I'm trying to run the debugger in VSCode using Bazel on a C++ application on MacOS 11. When I try to run this, I get the error message : "Could not load source 'testcpp.cc': 'SourceRequest' not supported". I'm not sure what I need to do to resolve this...it compiles and debugs properly on the command line. Here is my BUILD file:

```
package(
    default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name="testcpp",
    srcs=["testcpp.cc"],
)
```

Here is my .vscode/tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test dummy app",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "bazel build -c dbg --strip=never --spawn_strategy=standalone :testcpp"
        },
    ]
}
```

And here is my .vscode/launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "preLaunchTask": "test dummy app",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/testcpp",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any resolution to this issue?  I'm running into the same problem.  I followed the GitHub link in the only current answer, but the `sourceFileMap` suggestion didn't seem to help.

Comment: I was actually able to get this working in my project using `sourceFileMap`.  I added my suggestion as a comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and the only thing I could find was on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3831

I wasn't able to fix mine that way (maybe because I'm using lldb instead of gdb) but it seems like you should change the current working directory to the executable's and then add the appropriate source file map as written in the last post of the issue.

Comment: This ended up working for me. I think you'll need to include this into your launch.json.

`"sourceFileMap": { "./": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/testcpp/" },`